# PhpStorm: how to tell the var type of an array member?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, intellisense, phpdoc

I use `PhpStorm 2016.2.1` IDE. I have a typed array (all members will be of the same, known class) and I'd like the IDE to know the type so I it can help me out with autocomplete/intellisense.

```
class MyClass{    
     /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $userArray;

    public addUser($uid){ $this->$userArray[$uid] = new User($uid); }

    public processUser($uid){

        $oUser = $this->$userArray[$uid];
            //since the PHP array can contain anything, the IDE makes 
            //no assumption about what data type $oUser is. How to let it 
            //know that it's of type User?
    }
}
```

I have tried...

```
 /**
 * @var User
 */
public $oUser = ...;
```

And also

```
 /**
 * @type User
 */
public $oUser = ...;
```

So far, the only thing I've gotten to work is to use getter functions:

```
/**
* @return User
*/
function getUser($uid){ return $this->$userArray[$uid]; }

function processUser($uid){
    //now the IDE knows the type of $oUser
    $oUser = $this->getUser($uid);
}
```

But slowing down the script with unneeded function calls just to get better IDE support seems like a bad idea.

Any idea how I can let PhpStorm know the type of a variable? Or even better: how to tell it which type an array will contain in the `PHPDoc` metadata for that array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For class variables, as you know, you can simply do

`@var User`

For local variables, it's not officially a supported format, but you must also specify the variable name:

`@var User $oUser`

Specific to PHPStorm, you'll need to use double asterisks (I think it's the only IDE that needs it, please consider that):

`/** @var User $oUser */`

See the [PHPDoc manual](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html) for more info

Comment: Thanks; that works for the local variable!  Is there a way to indicate typed arrays? (tell the IDE that all array members are of a given class)

Comment: You can do `@var User[]` to suggest an array of User objects, but I don't know if PHPStorm supports it yet (it might!) https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html#arrays

Comment: Another option is to provide a hint within the foreach loop, bit messy though

Comment: `@var User[]` worked too :-)  IDE says `$oUser` if of type `User|mixed`